# $f_n \to f$, $g_n \to g$ $\mu$-almost everywhere then $f_n + g_n \to g + f$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have to prove that if $f_n \to f$, $g_n \to g$ $\mu$-almost everywhere then $f_n + g_n \to g + f$ almost everywhere.

It could be proven easily if I knew that $f_n \to 0, g_n \to 0 \implies f_n + g_n \to 0$ but I'm stuck on that too(because $f_n \to f \iff f_n - f \to 0$ and then my original question could be formed as $(f_n - f) + (g_n - g) \to 0$. I appreciate any help.

Comment: I'd say that technically, in order to claim that $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere implies $f_n-f\to 0$ almost everywhere, you need the thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exists $A,B \subseteq X $  such that $\mu(A^c)=\mu(B^c)=0$

And $f_n(x) \to f(x),\forall x \in A$ and $g_n(x) \to g(x),\forall x \in B$

So $\forall x \in A \cap B$ we have that $f_n(x)+g_n(x) \to f(x)+g(x)$ and $\mu((A\cap B)^c) \leq \mu(A^c)+\mu(B^c)=0$

Thus $f_n+g_n \to f+g$ a.e

Comment: Is the theory true without ordering the almost everywhere convergence? (Just order the convergence in $\mu$).

Comment: @Usermat yes it is true if we consider convergence in measure.